# How to define a custom date-time object in VBA for Macro programming

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm learning VBA basics. I have day, month, year, hour, minute, second data in variables. How do I construct a date-time object from these values?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at the `DateSerial` and `TimeSerial` functions?  Search for HELP on how Excel stores dates/times.

Answer (score 4):

Normally a date would just be represented as a `Date` data type.  A Date is stored as a double precision number, representing the number of days since 31 December 1899.  Time is represented as a fraction of a day, e.g. 6:00am is represented by .25.

You can then assign values to Date variables using such methods as

```
Dim myDate As Date
myDate = Now()
myDate = DateValue("30 July 2016")
myDate = DateSerial(2016,7,30)
' or even myDate = DateSerial(2016,7,30+20) which is equivalent to myDate = DateSerial(2016,8,19)
myDate = TimeValue("19:22:56")
```

or if you have variables containing your year, month, day, etc you might calculate the Date value as

```
myDate = DateSerial(myYear, myMonth, myDay) + TimeSerial(myHour, myMinute, mySecond)
```

If you don't want to use the `Date` data type, you can create your own using something like

```
Type myDateType
    myDay as Integer
    myMonth as Integer
    myYear as Integer
    myHour as Integer
    myMinute as Integer
    mySecond as Integer
End Type
```

and then declare variables by something like

```
Dim myDateVariable as myDateType
```

and reference the various parts of the type by something like

```
myDateVariable.myYear = 2016
```